# How to use javascript date object to display opening times of a shop

Tags: javascript

I want to write a function in javascript that expects to get:
1) opening times object for the days
2) GMT (in my case new york time)

and it will return if the shop is open or closed.
a user can be in a different time zone so his computer won't be in NY time so I must take this in consideration.

Can it be done client side?

Further explanation:
I'm a user in Hawaii and when I enter the website, I would like to display if the shop is open now in New York

I'm a user in UK and when I enter the website, I would like to display if the shop is open now in New York.

In the client side I have user's local time and the users can be in different time zones so I would like for the client side to determine if the shop in new york now is open (giving array of days and times the shop is open) considering the different time zones

Comment: Can you please detail the question? 
Moreover what do you mean by GMT ? it means Greenwich Mean Time and "GMT (in my case new york time)" does not make sense.
What does "opening times object for the days" mean?
The question definetely need rephrasing.

Comment: I'm guessing that's the difference from GMT to where the user is (NY is minus 5 or something)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) for managing dates and time, than just directly using the Date object. There is support for different locales and timezones.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in:
http://pellepim.bitbucket.org/jstz/

You can make a switch/case with the values and calculate the timezone

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can display dates and times on the client. There's probably two main things you want to do:

1) Store your dates as UTC dates. This is the recommended format for storing dates and is agnostic of timezone. Normally you'll send the data after calling [date.toISOString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)

2) I'd also recommend using [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) to format across timezones:

```
var openTime = moment(dateString);
var newYorkTime = moment.clone().tz("America/New_York");
newYorkTime.format();
```